# Wordpress portfolio filter is not working with cyrillic categories names

Tags: wordpress, categories, cyrillic

At my website portfolio filter is not working with **cyrillic** categories names while its working perfectly for **latin** letters.

On my wordpress website, portfolio page, when I choose to be shown only let's say 3 categories on it and I name them with cyrillic names (Сватби, Портрети) or just numbers (2017;2018; etc) the projects doesn't show up.

But everything is showing when I use latin letters instead. Or when I click Show All categories, also no problems.

```
<?php



    if( $page_title_type == '1' || $page_title_type == '2' )
    {
        ?><h5><?php the_title();?></h5><?php
    }


    $portfolio_category = get_page_setting_property( 'portfolio_category', '' );
    $portfolio_categories = get_categories(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'project_cat',
    ));

    if($portfolio_category == '')
    {
        $portfolio_filter_enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $portfolio_filter_comma = strpos($portfolio_category, ',');
        $portfolio_filter_enabled = $portfolio_filter_comma !== false && $portfolio_filter_comma > 0;
    }

    if( $portfolio_filter_enabled && count( $portfolio_categories ) > 1 )
    {
        ?>
        <div class="filter">
            <i class="category-icon"></i>
            <ul class="filter-ctrl">
                <li class="active" data-filter="*"><i><?php esc_html_e('Show All', 'mytheme'); ?></i></li>
        <?php

        if($portfolio_category == '')
        {
            foreach($portfolio_categories as $cat)
            {
                ?><li data-filter=".filter-cat-<?php echo esc_attr($cat->term_id); ?>"><i><?php echo esc_html($cat->name); ?></i></li><?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $cats = explode(',', $portfolio_category);
            foreach($portfolio_categories as $cat)
            {
                if(in_array($cat->name, $cats))
                {
                    ?><li data-filter=".filter-cat-<?php echo esc_attr($cat->term_id); ?>"><i><?php echo esc_html($cat->name); ?></i></li><?php
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <?php
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the JS for a quick and easy fix replace:

```
var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
```

->

```
var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter').replace(/%/g, '\\%');
```

The proper way to ultimately fix this for any character would be to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape or equivalent shim, however the above should be just enough.